# Which Python Environment Does Pydev Use?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When I press CTRL+F9 to run tests in Pydev, which interpreter does it use?

For example, I have Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 installed.

When I run scripts in the console by pressing CTRL+Shift+Enter, a window pops up that lets me choose interpreter. But this does not happen when running tests.

Answer (score 1):

you can check by going to :

```
window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - (Python/Jython/IronPython).
```

If you want to know for running test, then it's in run configurations, you can create specific run configuration and tell him which version to execute with

Answer (score 0):

Before you use an interpreter which is already installed on your computer, you may need to [add another interpreter](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html):

From the menu... window > preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - (Python/Jython/IronPython).

Now [run](http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html) your application:
menu... Run->Run As->Python Run

If the commands and options are not exactly what you want then you need to create a run configuration:
Right-click on the project ->run -> run configurations

Answer (score 0):

It'll be either the default interpreter (the top one at the preferences > pydev > interpreter) or the one that's configured for the project (if you select the project > alt+enter > pydev-interpreter/grammar you can let 'default' or select a different one).

After you've done a launch, you can go to run > run configurations and change it for the created launch.